# Copy MQ segmentation enabled messages to multiple queues on IBM MQ 9.2.0.7

Tags: ibm-mq

We are running on IBM Series version 9.2.0.7 on Linux servers. We have a requirement to copy the messages onto multiple MQ queues whenever the message reaches the input queue. We tried the below 2 options they work fine in many cases but they fail when the input messages have segmentation enabled.

We tried the below things, it works fine for normal messages. But it fails when we enable segmentation in MQ message header while putting the messages.

1. Simple MQ Pub Sub Setup to copy the messages onto multiple queues. Application is not able to put the segmentation enabled messages. We are getting mqrc 2417[MQRC_MSG_NOT_ALLOWED_IN_GROUP]
2. Message Multiplexer from Capitalware. The mmx process is not able to process the incoming message and it's failing with mqrc 2142[MQRC_HEADER_ERROR] error.

Please note both the options works fine for all the messages. But they fail only when we enable segmentation in MQ message header while putting the messages.

Kindly let us know if you have faced this problem and if yes kindly let us know the possible options.

Comment: MQ topics don't support message groups or segmentation. And I think the same is true for the Message Multiplexer, though it's not in the documentation explicitly, but as it reads messages as a client application it would need support for message segmentation. You could try the Capitalware MQ Message Replication API exit, that has a better chance of working, or you could write your own program where you can control how your program handles segmented messages.